How can I use both WSL2 and the Android Studio emulator?
I usually use WSL2+VSCode, but am starting to use Android Studio. I cannot seem to run both the Android Studio emulator and use WSL2 at the same time.

I cannot install HAXM without first disabling Hyper-V. I tried disabling Hyper-V and the Hypervisor platform and after a few restarts I was able to install HAXM. There was still an error with running the virtual device emulator but I did not investigate further.
From looking online it seems people are able to use Hyper-V as the emulator on Android Studio. I am using Windows 10 Pro version 22H2. Is this possible on my machine?
I can connect and use physical devices from Studio without issue.
It is a pain to have to disable one, then restart etc. if I want to switch between HAXM for AS and Hyper-V for WSL2

Seems like you are using an older version of Android Studio and/or Android emulator because HAXM is deprecated and is no longer used by recent emulator versions.

Thank you for responding. I originally installed Android Studio when I had Windows 10 Home. I got Windows 10 Pro a few days ago and then reinstalled AS Koala but it still asks for HAXM... I think I will try reinstalling again

May be you still have the old Android SDK installed. Open Android SDK manager in Android Studio and update emulator. Emulator version I have is 35.1.4. For the alternatives of HAXM see https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows

Emulator version that is available on SDK manager is 34.2.15 :\
Any idea how I can get 35.1.4?
